Variance decomposition with Tweedie distribution – back transform necessary?
We are running a hierarchical random intercept model with a Tweedie distributed dependent variable (see below) and three levels of hierarchy. Our aim is to estimate how much of the total variance (in percent) each level of the hierarchy explains. We do so by estimating the variance of the random intercepts for each level of the hierarchy and then divide it by the total variance.
The dependent variable is Tweedie distributed (continuous, zero inflated, right skewed). The priors for the random intercepts are normal distributions, for which we estimate the variance. Given that we use a Tweedie distribution for the DV, do we need to back transform or inverse transform the variance estimates of the individual random effects to correctly estimate the share of the variance explained or is no back transform necessary?
Note that we are NOT using a log link function in the model, as frequently done for Tweedie distributions. The mean of the Tweedie distribution is simply determined by adding a couple of variables.
